# Подсчет элементов вектора в R

Tags: r, vector, rstudio, diff, rle

Функция которая на вход принимает вектор любой длинны состоящий из нулей и единиц. Допустим каждая единица- полученная выплата за ребенка. Если кол-во нуле после серии единиц превышает пять, это свидетельствует о появлении нового ребенка. Таким образом:
вектор (0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1) должен выдавать аутпут (0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
вектор (1,1,1,0,0,1) выдает (1,1,1,1,1,1) 
вектор (0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,) выдает (0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
Лектор посоветовал использовать функции cumsum(), rle(), diff(), which

Мои мысли на эту тему:
функция rle$length поможет мне найти гэпы после которых количество детей увеличивается
какая-то итерация с использованием diff поможет мне сохранять ряд в векторе (делать его последовательным)
если суммировать единицы то получается арифмет. последовательность 12345, и функция дифф как раз даст мне ряд единиц.

Я сталкиваюсь с проблемами:
не могу подобрать подходящую итерацию, сохранив при этом изначальную длину вектора, прошу дать мне какие-то подсказки, знаю, что задание несложное, но я начинающий...

Comment: Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, описать задачу более четко и ясно

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то код функции может быть реализован, например, так:

```
fun <- function(x) {
    # Результирующий вектор
    res <- integer(length(x))
    # Индекс первой единицы
    i <- min(which(x > 0))
    # Присваиваем единицу
    res[i] <- 1
    # RLE
    r <- rle(x)
    # Определение позиций пяти нулей подряд
    i <- r$values == 0 & r$lengths >= 5
    # Определение индекса следюущего за пятью нулями
    i <- cumsum(r$lengths)[i] + 1
    # Присваиваем единицу
    res[i] <- 1
    # Расставляем значения
    res <- cumsum(res)
    return(res)
}
```

Проверить на данных из вопроса:

```
x <- list(
    c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1),
    c(1,1,1,0,0,1),
    c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
)
lapply(x, fun)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Ответы совпадают с примера из вопроса.